# Overriding simple-jwt's TokenObtainPairSerializer to implement 2FA

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, multi-factor-authentication

I am currently trying to implement 2-Factor Authentication in my Django Application. The first thing I've done is to modify the `Meta` class in the `UserSerializer` class to add two fields `enabled` (boolean indicating if 2FA is enabled for a user) and `secret_key` (the key to generate OTP, that is shared to the user when he enables 2FA).

To minimally modify the login flow, I've modified the form that is sent to generate the access tokens to include a new field "otp". The user can fill it or not, and the backend will check if the user has 2FA enabled, and if yes, if the OTP is correct.

Without 2FA, the login is simply a POST request with body `{"username": usr, "password": pwd}`. This has become a POST request with body `{"username": usr, "password": pwd, "otp": otp}`. If a user user hasn't enabled 2FA, he can simply leave the `opt` field blank.

My `urls.py` looks like this:

```
path("api/token/", TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name="token_obtain_pair")
```

My idea is to override TokenObtainPairView to adapt to the new request. From what I've found, I have to change the `validate` method, but I don't really have a clue as to how to do that. I probably would have to get the values of the `enabled` and `secret_key` fields of the user (based on username) to generate the OTP (if relevant) and check it against the `otp` field. Problem is, I don't know how to do that and I'm getting a little bit lost in the simple-jwt implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I wont provide full solution to your problem, but it might be a good start.

Create your custom **LoginView**:

```
class LoginView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
```

Implement your own serializer which inherits **TokenObtainPairSerializer**:

```
class LoginSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        # implement your logic here
        # data = super().validate(attrs)
        return data
```

Change **urls.py**

```
path("api/token/", LoginView.as_view(), name="token_obtain_pair")
```

This is how **TokenObtainSerializer** looks like:

```
class TokenObtainSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username_field = User.USERNAME_FIELD

    default_error_messages = {
        'no_active_account': _('No active account found with the given credentials')
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields[self.username_field] = serializers.CharField()
        self.fields['password'] = PasswordField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        authenticate_kwargs = {
            self.username_field: attrs[self.username_field],
            'password': attrs['password'],
        }
        try:
            authenticate_kwargs['request'] = self.context['request']
        except KeyError:
            pass

        self.user = authenticate(**authenticate_kwargs)

        if not getattr(login_rule, user_eligible_for_login)(self.user):
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
                self.error_messages['no_active_account'],
                'no_active_account',
            )

        return {}
```

So you could implement `__init___` in your own serializer and add your **otp** field and implement logic you want inside `validate` method(you can access **self.user** here and check if he has **2FA** enabled or not).

Comment: What should I do if I don't want to use the default username, password fields and use user_uuid instead?